# Machine Learning - Independent Column with Text data type

Tags: python, machine-learning

In my dataset there is an independent column called "Cycle". It has date values written in text format. I am not understanding how to convert it into numbers. I am working with Multiple Linear Regression and Python. The Column looks like this. Any idea regarding this.

---

```
    Cycle
```

---

### 10th June to 11th July

### 20th June to 21st July

### 17th June to 18th July

Comment: What have you attempted so far? What have you researched? Post some code. Maybe read the question guidelines? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just want to know what will be the best approach to move forward. I can split them into two columns, so that only numbers will be there. OR Do I have to maintain this format (As it is mentioned as an Independent Variable in the data set). But if I maintain this format then it will be very hard for me to convert it into numbers.. Please give me ideas whether to maintain this format or I can split as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea regarding this

Disclaimer: Since you question is broad and quite vague on details answer is aimed at only at pointing you where to research and some general terms around it.

This is example of categorical data. In a nutshell you can do several things with it, here are presented some ideas:

- If categories are fixed and you know all possible values you can convert them to numerical values by assigning each of them incremental (or new random) number.
- If your categories are not known in advance you can convert them to hashed category. As a variation of this approach you can hash only most frequent categories and summary reduce outliers to smaller number of hash values reducing total amount of categories used.
- You can bucketize them, depending on your expected impact and here are just some ideas:

  - bucketize in month chunks:
  - bucketize in quartal chunks
  - bucketize in weeks chunks
- Finally you can transform it to more detailed representation, getting 
  additional value out of it like so (this is just an example):

  ```
  Cycle                   C_Start_Day  C_Start_Month  C_End_Day  C_End_Month  C_Num_Days
  10th June to 11th July  10           6              11         7            1
  20th June to 21st July  20           6              21         7            1
  17th June to 18th July  17           6              18         7            1
  ```

Note: based on your previous comment I'd suggest using last approach (transformation). that way you can extract from `Cycle` column all the data you need for further numerical processing.

Comment: yes I am going with the last approach. They are not categorical values..